# Request tampering over SSL using man-in-the-middle attack

Tags: security, penetration-testing

I am familiar with SSL/TLS and its mechanism to protect data sent over HTTP between the browser and the web server.  One of the issues identified by my security testing team is **request tampering over SSL** where they were able to modify the HTTP request payload of a POST request using **man-in-the-middle attack**.  The browser obviously did show a certificate validity warning and it was ignored.

In my opinion, the application shouldn't handle or remediate such request tampering scenarios because SSL/TLS takes care of it.  Server side validation of data that matches any client side validation should suffice to ensure that the HTTP payload is valid.

So my question is basically to confirm my understanding about this.  Is request tampering using man-in-the-middle attack over SSL a valid security testing scenario? And should an application do any specific request encoding to protect from such attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is a valid testing scenario.

Depending on the threat model of your application, the application might implement *Certificate Pinning*, to mitigate that threat. With that, you can make sure that only a specific cert (or certs signed by a certain CA are trusted.

See [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/29990/21017) for reference.